# Highlight entire row in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have this table:

```
        ID CODE     NAME    Percentage  unit    sales
         6494      Orange      0%        2      74.00 
          582      apple       0%        1      90.00 
SubTotal                       1%        3     164.00 
         6493      Banana     171%      951    25,677.00 
         6494    Strawberry    33%      182    6,734.00 
SubTotal                       204%     1133   32,411.00 
Grand Total                    205%     1136   32,575.00
```

and I want to highlight all cells until the last column that contains the word "TOTAL".

This code highlighted only the cells that contains "Total". How can I highlight the entire row?

```
MySearch = Array("Total")
myColor = Array("3")
For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

    With sh.Cells
        .Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone

        For I = LBound(MySearch) To UBound(MySearch)

            Set Rng = .Find(What:=MySearch, After:=ActiveSheet.Range("J8"), LookIn:=xlValues, MatchCase:=False)
            If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
                FirstAddress = Rng.Address
                Do
                    Rng.Interior.ColorIndex = myColor(I)
                    Set Rng = .FindNext(Rng)
                Loop While Not Rng Is Nothing And Rng.Address <> FirstAddress
            End If
        Next I
    End With
Next sh
```

Comment: Please fix the formatting of the subtotals/totals to get a clearer understanding of the data

Comment: here you go, i hope u can help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the line where you set the `ColorIndex` to select the whole line before setting the colour.  Try this:-

```
'This selects the whole line, based on the resultant "Rng" cell returned by "Find".
'It uses CurrentRegion to determine number of columns in the vicinity.
Range(Rng, Cells(Rng.Row, Rng.Column + Rng.CurrentRegion.Columns.Count - 1)).Interior.ColorIndex = myColor(I)
```

Comment: i have this error in ur line, Method Range of object _Global failed. what should i do ?

Comment: Have you declared Rng?   `Dim Rng As Range`

Comment: It sounds like there is a blank worksheet or the data is not consistent across each worksheet